# Is there an issue with the BaseX 9.5.1 build?

Tags: lucene, basex

Getting this message in .log:

!ENTRY org.eclipse.help.base 2 0 2021-03-02 16:03:03.323
!MESSAGE Unable to consume Lucene index from bundle 'org.eclipse.wst.dtdeditor.doc.user_1.1.0.v201903222120 [425]'. The index should be rebuilt with Lucene 8.4.1

Basex version: 9.5.1
Platform: Mac OS 10.13.6
Java: 1.8.0_251-b08
Eclipse: 2020-03
Lucene version in POM: org.apache:lucene-stemmers:3.4.0

Does this matter?

Comment: It’s difficult to tell what’s happening in your project (Lucene is not part of the BaseX distribution). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example on how to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Christian.

The fact is that I can't reproduce it.  Combining this with the fact that I have no plans to work with non-English data, I must conclude that no identifiable issue exists.

Arthur